# Update YAML value on CLI

Tags: bash, awk, sed, yaml, command-line-interface

I want to change yaml file value based key on **backend.image.tag**

I already used *yq* like tools but unfortunately format is breaking when updating value. So i want to update a value on yaml file with awk sed etc. utils.

Gived yaml file:

```yaml
frontend:
  # Some comments
  image:
    repository: frontend
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    tag: "1.0.0"

# Some comments

backend:

  image:
    repository: backend
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    tag: "1.3.1.beta-2cdfxq2"
```

Expected yaml file:

```yaml
frontend:
  # Some comments
  image:
    repository: frontend
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    tag: "1.0.0"

# Some comments

backend:

  image:
    repository: backend
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    tag: "1.3.2"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in form of code which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: Parsing YAML with a RegEx engine is as complex as writing any other YAML implementation, so I advise against it. It can be done, though some people will tell you it can't because they confuse RegEx with regular languages. Be aware that when you do something simple like matching for example `^\s*tag:\s+"([^"]*)"\s*$` it works for your example but will also match any other quoted value with the key `tag:` anywhere. You need to define your preconditions (like, can there be any other `tag:` key anywhere) before anyone can help you craft a RegEx usable for this that does not implement all of YAML.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/633696/133219. Just call the script I posted at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/633740/133219 as `awk -v tgt='backend.image.tag' -v val='"1.3.2"' -f tst.awk file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have indicated, a dedicated yaml processor such as jq is always preferred but the following maybe another option:

```
awk '/^[[:alnum:]]+:$/ { label=$1 } /^[[:space:]]+image:$/ { img=1 } /^[[:space:]]+tag:/ && img==1 && label=="backend:" { img=0;gsub("\".*\"","\"1.3.1\"",$0);print;next }1' file
```

Explanation:

```
awk '/^[[:alnum:]]+:$/ { 
                          label=$1                                            # Search for tags anchored at the start of the line and track them by reading the result into the variable label.
                       } 
     /^[[:space:]]+image:$/ { 
                          img=1                                               # Search for image tags and if we find them, set a process flag img to 1
                       } 
     /^[[:space:]]+tag:/ && img==1 && label=="backend:" {                     # When label is backend, image process flag is 1 and current line is tag, process.
                          img=0;                                              # Reset the img flag
                          gsub("\".*\"","\"1.3.1\"",$0);                      # Replace anything in between quotes with 1.3.1                      
                          print;                                              # Print the resulting line
                          next                                                # Skip to the next line
                        }1' file                                              # Print all un amended lines through 1
```